# wordpress site is not loading css, what might be the problem?

Tags: html, css, wordpress, plugins

I wanted to increase page speed score.so i installed various plugins. Now my website is not loading css, this happened after installing w3 total cache.
[this is the website image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KKBjC.jpg)

Answer (score 2):

This commonly will be an issue with either the Minify CSS options within the W3 Total Cache plugin and also the Rewrite URL Structure.

Try This:
Disable the Cache settings: ( Performance > General settings ) Then purge cache after that and save all settings. Then Go to your wp-content folder and delete /cache/ folder.

After refresh the page. If this doesn't work try disabling the Minify CSS options. If that works, it seems you will need to manually minify the CSS files instead. If that also doesn't work try the same with the Rewrite URL Structure.

Comment: Deleting cache folders helped me.Thank you!